# Hyperledger-Composer: Why use Node.js instead of Angular?

Tags: node.js, angular, hyperledger-composer

When developing Hyperledger Composer applications, there is a typical solution architecture that looks as follows:

[image]

According to the docs there is an alternative solution architecture that uses Node.js (see https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/applications/node):

[image]

Why would one choose the second architecture (with node.js), given that this involves one step more: not only do you have to write a node.js application but you then also have to develop a front-end for this node.js application (so 2 steps).

In the case of the first architecture, one only has to create an Angular application (because the REST server just needs to be started but the REST API is generated automatically by the framework) and is done (so there is only 1 step).

Are there any arguments in favour of using Node.js I'm not seeing?

Comment: You also need a REST server according to that diagram (which may or may not be written in node), so the number of steps is the same. The steps are largely equivalent.

Comment: I just have to start the REST server. The REST API is generated automatically.

Comment: Okay, well if you already have a backend, then it doesn't make sense to create another. But bear in mind that Angular and a NodeJs backend are different things, and serve a different purpose, so you can't really pick one over the other

Comment: But I would write code to create the Node.js app and then I would need to write code again to create the front-end.

Comment: The question doesn't make sense, you're comparing apples to oranges. It isn't 'Angular vs Node'. It is 'Angular vs some frontend and 'REST server vs Node.js'. Angular is frontend framework. Node.js app can be REST server or not. First diagram is a special case of second diagram. Second diagram possibly shows the architecture for non-SPA that is rendered on server side, while Angular is mostly used in SPA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case for node.js is only if you don't want to create a user interface, or, if you wish to create wrappers around the existing hyperledger endpoints that reformat the consumption. A case could be that every day at 5pm you want to post an update to an asset based on what has changed in a different database somewhere... in this case you couldn't use Angular directly.

It's also important to note Angular is exclusively client side, Node.js is exclusively server side, and you cannot serve an API with Angular.

Separation of front end and back end is common practice now and is suggested for applications that contain both. Here's an article on it: https://quickleft.com/blog/six-reasons-we-split-front-end-and-back-end-code-into-two-git-repositories-working-with-github-repositories/

Comment: Thank you for your suggested answer. What does it mean when you write "You cannot run an API with Angular"? What does "running" an API mean? ... All I need to do is consume the REST API (generated by Hyperledger Composer) ... and creating an Angular app consuming the REST API is easy.

Comment: @Michael I think my answer was also only halfway there.. updated with a little more descriptions